# Work email for a sharepoint 2010 user group

Tags: administration

I would like to have a work email for my sharepoint 2010 user group, do not see any direct options.  how to set that?

Comment: What?  What user group are you referring to? And what are you trying to accomplish?  Thanks.

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. Please edit  your post and add details as requested by the community. It will be  closed for now, but don't worry - once you have improved the question  flag a moderator and it can be reopened. See our [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) for general guidelines.

Answer (score -2):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/send-e-mail-to-members-of-a-sharepoint-group-HA010086731.aspx

Comment: Please dont just add a link as answer! Add relevant info from the page you link to, then link! Links tend to be short lived compared to our site